# In R data table how do you subset and count?

Tags: r, datatable, aggregation

I have a set of data similar to this

```
a = data.table(
  ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  TOUR = c("USA", "CHINA", "CHINA", "CHINA", "EUROPE", "CANADA", "USA")
)
```

and I would like to aggregate the data to create this:

[image: What I'm aiming for]

Using data table.....Could anybody show my how?

Thank you, Phil,

Answer (score 3):

We can first create the "NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS" grouped by 'ID' with `.N` i.e. number of rows, and then `dcast` with `fun.aggregate as`length`

```
dcast(a[, NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS := .N, ID], ID + NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS ~ TOUR, length)
#    ID NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS CANADA CHINA EUROPE USA
#1:  1                  2      0     1      0   1
#2:  2                  3      0     2      1   0
#3:  3                  2      1     0      0   1
```

If we need the prefix `"TOUR"`, use the `paste`

```
dcast(a[, NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS := .N, ID], ID + NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS ~ 
                    paste0("TOUR_", TOUR), length)
```

---

The above method also create a column in the original dataset as we are assigning (`:=`).  If we want to avoid that, we can do a join

```
a[, .(NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS = .N), ID][dcast(a, ID ~ paste0("TOUR_", TOUR), length), on = .(ID)]
#   ID NUMBER_OF_BOOKINGS TOUR_CANADA TOUR_CHINA TOUR_EUROPE TOUR_USA
#1:  1                  2           0          1           0        1
#2:  2                  3           0          2           1        0
#3:  3                  2           1          0           0        1
```